# Do circa 1 THz radio telescope front end amplifiers actually down convert before amplifying? At what frequency does amplification become untenable?

Tags: radio-astronomy, radio-telescope, instruments

A discussion of how astronomers view where "radio" ends and "infrared" begins under [What does the celestial sphere look like in thermal IR?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/48393/7982) led me to wonder just how high of a frequency is currently electronically amplified in radio telescopes before it is instead down-converted via some local oscillator and mixer.

**Just for example** [ALMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atacama_Large_Millimeter_Array) has ten different frequency bands listed at ESO's [ALMA Receiver Bands](https://www.eso.org/public/teles-instr/alma/receiver-bands/).

The table says that the lowest two bands (35–50 and 65–90 GHz) use [High-electron-mobility transistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-electron-mobility_transistor) receiver technology, while the top eight use "SIS".

The top band (Band 10) is listed as 0.3–0.4 mm or 787–950 GHz with a Noise Temperature Specification of 344 Kelvin.

But I don't know how to find out for each of these bands how the front ends work; whether they amplify or mix and down-convert first. So I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Do circa 1 THz radio telescope front end amplifiers actually down convert before amplifying? At what frequency does amplification become untenable *for radio astronomy applications*?

Related and possibly helpful:

- [Highest frequency that's been imaged by a radio telescope?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35975/7982)
- [Has optical interferometry been done at radio frequency using heterodyning with a laser in a nonlinear material?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36633/7982) (yes!)
- [How does ALMA produce stable, mutually coherent ~THz local oscillators for all of their dishes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28666/7982)
- [Is there any work underway to push the long baseline capabilities of the Event Horizon Telescope to sub-millimeter wavelengths?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35757/7982)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An article in Astronomy & Astrophysics [1](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2015/05/aa25529-14/aa25529-14.html) (A. M. Baryshev et al., A&A 577, A129 (2015)) titled “The ALMA Band 9 receiver
Design, construction, characterization, first light” covers this.

The relevant quote from the Methods section is:

> The ALMA Band 9 receiver units (so-called “cartridges”), which are installed in the telescope’s front end, have been designed to detect and down-convert two orthogonal linear polarization components of the light collected by the ALMA antennas. The light entering the front end is refocused with a compact arrangement of mirrors, which is fully contained within the cartridge. The arrangement contains a grid to separate the polarizations and two beam splitters to combine each resulting beam with a local oscillator signal. The combined beams are fed into independent double-sideband mixers, each with a corrugated feedhorn coupling the radiation by way of a waveguide with backshort cavity into an impedance-tuned superconductor-insulator-superconductor (SIS) junction that performs the heterodyne down-conversion. Finally, the generated intermediate frequency (IF) signals are amplified by cryogenic and room-temperature HEMT amplifiers and exported to the telescope’s IF back end for further processing and, finally, correlation.

So, that covers band 9, not quite 10.

A recent article [Poster/paper](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/11453/114533Q/Upgrade-of-an-ALMA-Band-10-prototype-receiver-for-ASTE/10.1117/12.2561076.short) from SPIE. I don’t currently have access to the full paper, but the abstract includes

> A new 790 – 940 GHz heterodyne receiver, ASTE Band 10, was installed in October 2019 on ASTE (Atacama Submillimeter Telescope Experiment), a 10 m submillimeter telescope near of the ALMA site in Chile. An ALMA Band 10 prototype receiver was upgraded with SIS mixers employing high-Jc junctions.

which to me implies a very similar architecture. Note that this particular receiver is actually installed on a telescope near ALMA, intended to be focused as a test bed for Band 10 experiments (most ALMA time is spent on other bands).

As for what has (likely) been installed on ALMA, an article in [IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON APPLIED SUPERCONDUCTIVITY, VOL. 21, NO. 3, JUNE 2011](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5676213), p606-611 by Yasunori Fujii et al. discusses the prototype they developed. It also used a superconductor-insulator-superconductor (SIS) mixer on the front end to directly downconvert to a 4-12GHz intermediate frequency.

Comment: Very nice, *\thanks!* Just fyi [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/40653/7982) includes arguments that there are limits of "quantum noise in coherent amplifiers" that make it challenging to build electronic amplifiers at a THz; the phase noise would degrade interferometry.

Comment: Just fyi after further searching with "quantum noise amplifiers radio telescope" I found that slides 29 and 30 of [Engineering Aspects for
Radio Astronomy](https://events.asiaa.sinica.edu.tw/ssp/viewFile.php?i=e0ac09c7b674289316abbcb7ed062f65&t=L) by Yuh-Jing Hwang of ASIAA puts the crossover point for downconversion-first around 100 GHz, and the following slides outline various schemes including SIS. (there's also some background [here](https://slideplayer.com/slide/8133352/))

Comment: and now I've just asked in Signal Processing SE [Why can't quantum phase noise in radio astronomy amplifiers just be filtered out after down conversion, instead of down-converting first?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/82041/25659)